# why do I get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

```
var soundPoolLabel: UILabel {
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 90, width: 540, height: 94))
  label.text = "SoundPool"
  label.textColor = UIColor.black
  label.font = UIFont(name: "Bodoni 72 Oldstyle", size: 80)
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!)
  attributedString.addAttribute(kCTKernAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey, value: CGFloat(1.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
  label.attributedText = attributedString
  return label
}

soundPoolLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let topConstraint = soundPoolLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint])
```

Comment: I don't see enough details here to advise you

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: In the console, you'll see a list of commands that executed just prior to your crash. If you look through that, it will point you in the right direction re: where your problem lives.

Comment: the error the console outputs is lldb and thats all. Doesn't tell me what it is. the line producing the error is : NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint])

Comment: try `soundPoolLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true` instead.

Comment: @Mukesh I tried that already

Comment: You have not added the `Label` as subview of the `view`. You cannot add constraints without proper relationship between views.

Comment: @Mukesh I did it to subview

Answer (score 20):

The label should not be a computed property. It should be initialized only once.
Do something like this to fix the problem.

```
var soundPoolLabel: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 90, width: 540, height: 94))
  label.text = "SoundPool"
  label.textColor = UIColor.black
  label.font = UIFont(name: "Bodoni 72 Oldstyle", size: 80)
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!)
  attributedString.addAttribute(kCTKernAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey, value: CGFloat(1.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
  label.attributedText = attributedString
  return label
}()
```

The reason for this is because every time you use `soundPoolLabel`, it will create a new instance of it instead of using the same one.
The system can't find the new instance in the subview hierarchy, throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: In my case problem was in adding a computed property. And then trying to add constraints to this property. You helped me Thanks!

Comment: Hi @OlehH how do you fix your issue, have same issue as yours using swift v5.7

Comment: I don't remember my case. But I guess your issue has the same root. Every call to the var creates a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I added a custom font that was not added into Info.plist. After adding under "Fonts provided by application" everything worked like a charm.